# multiple months display for angular bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

Is there an option in Angular UI Bootstrap Datepicker to display multiple months? like `numberOfMonths` option in JQuery datepicker.

Comment: Do you have any update or what did you use?

Comment: I switched to JQuery calendar, here is the Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/s71WDURou0QlRzM8Kjkc?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Use 2 datepickers with different models:

[Here is a plunker:](http://plnkr.co/edit/GSguZtAOj6to0PoKWtFR?p=preview)

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">

<div ng-form class="btn-group" dropdown>

    <datepicker ng-model="main.startDate" max-date="main.endDate"></datepicker>
    <datepicker ng-model="main.endDate" min-date="main.startDate"></datepicker>

</div>
<p>{{main.startDate | date:'EEEE MMMM d'}} - {{main.endDate | date:'EEEE MMMM d'}}</p>
```

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  this.startDate = new Date();
  this.endDate = new Date(this.startDate.getTime() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
});
```